# Missing comments

Tags: support, comment, deletion

If I've noticed correctly, some of my comments seem to be deleted by somebody else. The first time I didn't pay attention to this event, but I believe it happened again [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413085/5887). I've asked OP in the comment to his question whether he assumes that $q<1$, and OP responded that this can be assumed. He further put this assumption into the body of the question.

Now I can only see the next comment of mine starting with `Then...` but not the first two comments. Checking out the timeline of the post didn't help to realize what had happened. Perhaps, OP has deleted his own comment, but unlikely he could do this with mine. For sure, these comments were of a limited usefulness after the edit, but shall it mean the are to be deleted?

Edited: I've found [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9724/5887) which as well hints upon the thing.

Comment: Only you or a mod can delete comments; we should probably wait for a mod to chime in and maybe talk about the comment history for that post.

Comment: @Ｊ.M.: that was my guess as well, so I actually wonder whether this is indeed the case when mod shall delete a comment.

Answer (score 12):

Only one comment seems to have been deleted. It was the comment "Do you assume that the limit $q<1$?" Since that had been corrected, someone flagged it as obsolete and a moderator deleted it.

I don't see a comment by the OP. Perhaps they deleted their comment within 2 minutes of making it. I'm not sure, but that might keep it from being logged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, perhaps indeed OP deleted the first comment. Is it in a power of a moderator to decide whether the comment regarding the math side of the OP's content is obsolete or not? In the current situation I would agree, but since it's not the first time, I'm not very comfortable with a feeling that my comments may be deleted if they're counted as obsolete by somebody and a moderator. Perhaps, in some situations I would disagree - but I wouldn't even know they are deleted.

Comment: [Comments are ephemeral](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130975). Generally, informative content is not deleted. However, if there is content that should be kept permanently, then the best thing to do is to [include it in the question or answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/remove-the-ability-to-delete-comments-from-the-moderator-toolbox#comment86815_39296), if possible.